# Importing tkinter in Flask

Tags: python, flask, tkinter, python-3.4, pythonanywhere

I'm new to PythonAnywhere, and when I try to import tkinter using Flask putting `from tkinter import *`
after the line `from flask import Flask`, it shows an error saying: "`'from tkinter import *' used; unable to detect undefined names`".

How do I have to import tkinter, then?

Answer (score 3):

Your code editor is automatically running a linter like `flake8` or `pyflakes`, and it is this linter that tells you that it cannot detect common coding errors because you are using a `from <modulename> import *` statement. That's because a linter cannot know up front what names that statement will import.

In other words, this is **not a Python error**. Nor is it specific to PythonAnywhere.

You can avoid the message by importing only what you are actually using in your code:

```
from tkinter import Frame, StringVar, Label
```

Comment: ... or even better, don't do a global import at all.